# Regex to match begin pattern and first AND ONLY FIRST occurrence of end pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        Blah Blah
        Blah Blah
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Blah Blah
        Blah Blah
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

and the following regex:

```
GlobalSection\(TeamFoundationVersionControl\)((.|\n)*)(EndGlobalSection\r)
```

I want to find just the first GlobalSection for **TeamFoundationVersionControl** i.e. just the following:

GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        Blah Blah
        Blah Blah
    EndGlobalSection

The regex isn't working!  It selects the following i.e. BOTH sections (wrong!):

```
       GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
            Blah Blah
            Blah Blah
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Blah Blah
            Blah Blah
        EndGlobalSection
```

I need it to stop at the FIRST occurrence of EndGlobalSection.  Please help!

BTW: I am testing this with Regex Storm , an online RegEx tester.

Thank You!

Comment: `GlobalSection\(TeamFoundationVersionControl\)([\s\S]*?)EndGlobalSection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [non-greedy `*?` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), it'll terminate as soon as possible (before the first `EndGlobalSection`):

```
GlobalSection\(TeamFoundationVersionControl\)((.|\n)*?)EndGlobalSection
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bdUXD3/2).

If the regex engine you use supports [inline modifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers), you can activate the [`DOTALL` (or *single-line*) mode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall), allowing the dot to match newline characters (use the `s` modifier, except in Ruby where it's called `m`):

```
(?s)GlobalSection\(TeamFoundationVersionControl\)(.*?)EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` is simpler than `((.|\n)*?)`

Comment: It's simpler, you're just missing a capture group.

Comment: `.*?` is even simpler when you turn on the single-line mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer randomir, this is the one!

Comment: @user1967239, you are very welcome! Btw, on StackOverflow, we have a way of marking the answer as the solution by [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). In general (after you have 15+ rep) you can upvote helpful answers (either to yours or any other question), as well as upvote questions. That way the good and helpful answers/questions receive better visibility (they are listed first) when someone else comes along searching for an answer to their problem.